# how to pass parameters when writing own jquery plugin

Tags: jquery-plugins, parameter-passing, undefined, javascript

I am using the following pattern to write a javascript library, but it couldn't receive parameters passed into the functions, am I missing something here?

```
(function($){

    var Foo = function(elements, options){
    ... ...
    }


    Foo.prototype = {

        constructor: Foo,

        bar: function(arg){        
            console.log(arg);     // print 'undefined' here
        },

    }

    $.fn.foo = function(option){
        return this.each(function(){
        ... ...
        })
    }

    $.fn.foo.Constructor = Bricker

    $.fn.foo.defaults = {
        ... ...
    }

})(jQuery)
```

When I call $('select').foo('bar', content), content will be logged as 'undefined', can anyone tell me the problems?

Comment: Your `$.fn.foo()` method only takes one argument (`option`), so the second argument you're passing (`content`) is not actually accessible within its scope. Try `$.fn.foo = function(option, content) { /* ... */ };`.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi it still says 'undefined'

Comment: Then I'm afraid you'll have to fill the dots in your question, because it will be hard to answer without seeing how `$.fn.foo()` ends up calling `Foo.bar()`.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I've found out the problem. You are right, I didn't pass the second argument to the functions. Thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

In this case `Foo.prototype` and `$.fn.foo` both are working differently try the below code for creating jquery function like,

```
;(function(){
    $.fn.foo = function(name,value){
       console.log(name,value);
    };
})(jQuery);
```

You can call it by any `jquery-selector` like

```
$('#id').foo('bar','value');// check your console to see the magic.
```

And, your second scenario(prototype) is somehow different, in which you are using prototype method(which differs from `jQuery.fn`), to work your code try the below,

```
var Foo = function() {};
Foo.prototype = {
    constructor: Foo,
    bar: function(arg){        
        console.log(arg); // print 'test' here
    }
};
var f=new Foo();
f.bar('test');
```

```js
;(function($){
    $.fn.foo = function(name,value){
           console.log(name,value);
    };
})(jQuery);
$(document).foo('bar','value');

var Foo = function() {};
Foo.prototype = {
    constructor: Foo,
    bar: function(arg){        
        console.log(arg);     // print 'undefined' here
    }
};
var f=new Foo();
f.bar('test');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/42tm3b7c/) and [an explanatory answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/310914/1817690) for your doubts.